# Drag from sortable to droppable?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, droppable

Not sure if this can be done, some have said no, need to be able to drag from a sortable and drop on a dropable and have the drop actually occur.  The jsfiddle is based on another example that implemented a trash can but I need the item to move to the new list. Note the drop only accepts items from sortable2.

http://jsfiddle.net/LrVMw/4/

```
$("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
    connectWith: '.connectedSortable, #drop_zone'
}).disableSelection();

$("#drop_zone").droppable({
    accept: "#sortable2 li",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    drop: function(ev, ui) {
      // ????        
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is, what do you want to do with the element once it is dropped?

For example, if you want to remove the element when it is dropped, like the trashcan example, your drop function looks like this:

```
$("#drop_zone").droppable({
    accept: ".connectedSortable li",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    drop: function(ev, ui) {
        $(ui.draggable[0]).remove();
    }
});
```

I've included an updated jsFiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/LrVMw/5/

Documentation on the drop event: http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop

If it is something else you want, then let me know.

**EDIT**

To remove the element from the list and add it to a list of the dropzone, you just have to add 1 line to the drop function:

```
$("#drop_zone").droppable({
    accept: ".connectedSortable li",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    drop: function (ev, ui) {
        $("<li></li>").text(ui.draggable.text()).appendTo(this); // It's this line
        ui.draggable.remove();
    }
});
```

Edited jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LrVMw/8/

**EDIT 2**

Instead of just getting the text from the `li` element that is dropped, we will get the full html of it, just abit of tweaking gives:

```
$("#drop_zone").droppable({
    accept: ".connectedSortable li",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    drop: function (ev, ui) {
        $("<li></li>").html(ui.draggable.html()).appendTo(this);
        ui.draggable.remove();
    }
});
```

And the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LrVMw/9/

Comment: As I said I need the item to move to the new list.

Comment: What is this new list we're talking about, is it the drop zone?

Comment: Yes, the new list is the drop zone.

Comment: +1 Jimmy, that gets the text in the box, the fiddle works, but in the app the li contains a table and that isn't being moved, just the text contained in the tds

Comment: Ah I see, another bit of tweaking coming your way then.